# 404 error in ajax call, wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using ajax to collect data from enquiry form, then data is send to another page, and this page supposed to send this data to my email.
The problem is when I click send button, I'm getting 404 error in firebug console.
In template (with ajax code) I use this call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo get_permalink(11); ?>",
        data: {
                name: $('.enquiryName').val(),
                email: $('.enquiryEmail').val(),
                comments: $('.enquiryComments').val()
        }
}).done(function(msg) {
    if (msg=='1') {
        alert('<strong>Your enquiry has been sent successfully.</strong>');
        $('.enquiryName').val('');
        $('.enquiryEmail').val('');
        $('.enquiryComments').val('');
    } else {
        $('.errorBox').html(msg);
    }
});
```

Target page is just another page created in wordpress, with very basic template. When I put to browser url bar this page address and press enter I get message **Nothing to send.**, which is correct.

What might be wrong? In ajax I get 404 error, in browser it's fine.

Comment: So url is not accurate. Is it relative URL or absolute?  Sorry, i'm not a wordpress user so i have no idea what is supposed to return method: `get_permalink(11);`

Comment: just do a 'view source' on the page and find your ajax call - you will probably find the URL you are echoing out is not as expected.

Comment: when use `get_permalink`, wordpress return absolute url. Url is correct. I already wrote that if I put this url to browser url bar, i can see correct content, i dont get 404 error.

Comment: You need to use a relative URL in a Ajax call...

Comment: @superphonic Why that? Better is to use absolute URL

Comment: I just tried to use relative URL, im getting 404 error again :/

Comment: Can you edit your post with the new relative URL you are using...?

Comment: @superphonic just did, again 404 in ajax, fine in browser

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get an instance of the Ajax URL in frontend.
To do that you need to enqueue your script and use the `WP` function `wp_localize_script`

so in your `functions.php`

```
function enqueue_AjaxURL() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jmy-Yourscript.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_AjaxURL' );
```

and in your JS file you can use the object:
`url: ajax_object.ajax_url,`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a relative URL in an Ajax call... replace `<?php echo get_permalink(11); ?>` with the actual relative URL and see if it works..

Comment: Is it a wordpress behaviour or what?

Comment: You can't use an absolute URL in an Ajax call. It has nothing to do with Wordpress. It's to prevent cross site scripting..

Comment: Hmm, that's new for me. I have used many times absolute URLs with ajax call, just like jsonp ones

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing absolute and relative URLs: http://kb.iu.edu/data/abwp.html  Anyway, ajax can use any kind of URL for any kind of request

Comment: Happen to all of us, especially monday morning... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace 
 url: "<?php echo get_permalink(11); ?>",
with
url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'
```

also you must pass an **'action'** param in your data which can then be attached to callback function

**must see this :**

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: i dont wont to send this data to admin-ajax.php because it won't send this data

Comment: why it wont send this data ?